# Boolean expression to logic circuit

Tags: digital-logic

I am having trouble trying to convert the boolean expression A and B or Not C to an all nor gate circuit i have tried a couple of times but cannot seem to get the circuit right using ALL NOR GATES only. Any help would be appreciated. I think I need about 6 gates in total but i keep getting lost and confused

[image]

this is what i submitted i will go back and change the curve on them so they appear to look more like NOR but the circuit is correct to the truth table

[image]

Hoefully this image looks a bit clearer. Note this is how the software performs meaning i can only select and insert imgages i cannot really change the curve so much of the gate itself only drag it out ever so slightly

[image]

that is the expression i came up with and a hand sketch of the circuit instructor just went on to say my simulation were not NOR gates

[image]

[image]

Comment: hint                   A and B=not(not A or not B)

Comment: This is homework without an attempt at solution, show us what you have done so far.

Comment: i have done lots! This is what i have and have but been told it is not correct i will inserrt image now.

Comment: Your image looks correct to me for (A.B) + !C but are you sure the question isn't to convert A.(B + !C)

Comment: No the question was to convert the expression into a logic circuit using only NOR Gates as an exercise should we only have NOR gates at our disposal. Yes it is a college exercise but my teacher simply replied to me saying these are not NOR gates thats all the feedback i am getting

Comment: There isn't much of a curve on the left hand side of the NOR gates in your image. It's possible that they could be mistaken for NAND gates.

Comment: As @James pointed out those look like the symbol for a nand gate. Maybe you have used the wrong symbol.

Comment: Ok i get what you are saying i will change the circuit layout and post up the image. I have gone through the truth table for this circuit and it is performing exactly how the truth table is written so i do not know what else he could mean.

Comment: what do you mean roy???

Comment: I am not expecting you to solve the problem Roy i am only asking for guidance in the circuit as to if i had too many not enough gates or if i was way off. I only use the software tool to test my calculations. I AM NOT LOOKING FOR SOMEONE TO DO IT FOR ME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A two-level implementation with NOR gates requires that the function is simplified into product-of-sums (POS) form.**

Your function \$F=AB+C' \$ is not in that form. Convert it into POS form, invert it twice, and use DeMorgan's Law to obtain a function that is realizable using only NOR gates.

### Edit

The first part is to convert the your function into POS form. This can be done elegantly by using the AND-distributive law
$$F=(A+C')(B+C') $$
Inverting this once gives
$$F'=[(A+C')(B+C')]'=(A+C')'+(B+C')' $$

All you have to do is invert the expression one last time, and you can realise the function with only NOR gates.

### Edit 2

From the comments

> i have already gotten the function down to the last step in the second last image i have been told that much is true, I think my actual software schematic may have been unreadable as when i test it against the truth table it all checks out

I think you have worked on this long enough. I will show you my solution.

Inverting \$F' \$ from the first edit leaves us with the final expression.
$$F''=F=[(A+C')'+(B+C')']' $$

So the circuit can be realized with 4 NOR gates like this.
[image]

**Note** that we here use that a NOR gate with duplicate inputs acts as an inverter. However, this is necessary as OP only can use NOR gates.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117310/discussion-on-answer-by-carl-boolean-expression-to-logic-circuit).